# I can't use the subclass type in superclasses methods in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let say I have this code:

```js
class SuperElement extends Something {
  render(subclassInstance: ???) {}
}

class MyElement extends SuperElement {
  render({ sayHello }) {
    sayHello('Foo');
  }

  sayHello(name: string);
}
```

Is there a way I can get my IDE to properly autocomplete in `render` (in `MyElement`)?

I tried to use `(subclassInstance: this)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: The idea in the title is incorrect. A superclass must not know anything about its subclasses. The subclasses may not even exist, after all. Express what you want to achieve.

Comment: From the code it seems that you need an interface but the relationship between `MyElement` and `SuperElement` is not correct in this case. The purpose of inheritance is specialization, not code reuse. And the relationship between `SuperElement` and the type of `subclassInstance` is neither specialization, nor code reuse. `subclassInstance` is a collaborator of `SuperElement` and subclassing is not the appropriate solution for this.

Comment: How do you want to use these classes? Build an example of usage in the [TypeScript playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and post a link to it in the question.

Comment: You can indeed refer to possible subclass types via [the `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), but subclasses do not inherit method param types from superclasses (see [ms/TS#23911](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911)) so you'll have to annotate if you want it to work, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WoY8aN). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @axiac I thought that defining the type in the parent class was going to reflect in the override in the child, that is why I use an extends here.

Comment: @jcalz Yes I think you explained pretty well, this is what I was concerned about, at least using your syntax I can get rid of the error in the child class, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually you do want to be using [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) to represent the type of potential subclasses.  This is essentially an implicit [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the implementing class, which only gets specified when called as a method later:

```
class SuperElement {
  render(subclassInstance: this) { }
}

new SuperElement().render;
// (method) SuperElement.render(subclassInstance: SuperElement): void
// this type inferred to be --------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^

class SomeSubElement extends SuperElement {
  foo = 123;
}    
new SomeSubElement().render;
// (method) SuperElement.render(subclassInstance: SomeSubElement): void
// this type inferred to be --------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Unfortunately when you override methods in TypeScript, the subclass does not infer its parameter types from the superclass type.  You have to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) them yourself and then it will be *checked* against the superclass method parameter types to ensure compatibility.  This is a longstanding pain point in TypeScript; the relevant open issue asking to inherit parameter types from parent classes is [microsoft/TypeScript#23911](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911).  Until and unless that is implemented, then, you're stuck with doing this:

```
class MyElement extends SuperElement {
  render({ sayHello }: this) {
    // annotate ---> ^^^^^^
    sayHello('Foo');
  }    
  sayHello(name: string) {}
}
```

which isn't great, but at least catches errors:

```
class OopsElement extends SuperElement {
  render({ sayHowdy }: this) { // error!
    //     ~~~~~~~~ <--
    // Property 'sayHowdy' does not exist on type 'OopsElement'    
  }
  sayHello(name: string) {}
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuAHApgJwKImQW2QOwBdoBvAKGmlXwBM0AKCeAI1EggEk8ICw9hkAXNAIALAJYQAlCWgBfUvNKk8yAO5wkaTDnwE6kgHRU8tVAG5SAekvQ6uUQHtq0hCgxZchIzXqMW4KE5uXn4hVy0PXUkhADcHMWolVig4B1wEJm1PImQADwIaGHD3HUIScmgAMwcHaABeaABGACYAZgtFFXVYNOQMrN19bxM0C2tbexEnF00S7OHTBmZkji4ePkFU9OYBwmjoOISlUhXoAFkAT12c-MKNN2vyimNF4mgIMAuACWQQEFrZEJRBJpGQKBRxrw8A4eAVoABaREAPmgAD10RiKhQPt9fv86AByABiNQJkgsFEU2M+Pz+DjoeDAuCE3FQYjwAHNQUpKQpjicAjAAPIORAQR55AomIqzR5gyg+VB0N44r4OVTUC5yIHiKQycZoVAOVAAQix0HG4OgAD9bXbbdAADyI83jAAKRrcBC1BNV6s1BOg1AcyBg0JuEiIDjwwguKGgBJFYuugfBFXk1NxdIZTM2rPZXJI8lkQA)

Comment: As you say it "isn't great", especially when you try to hide things so the end-user doesn't need to care much about details. But that's not too bad. Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: I actually found that if I write `render({}: this)` in the parent class, there is no error and it helps in the front.

Comment: I'm not sure what possible error you're talking about or "helps in the front" means.  Is this something that would change my answer or just a followup bit of information?

Comment: A followup :) all good!